# How to get the svn log data line by line

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-repository

I was getting the svn log information by using the below code

`svn log -v --limit 1` 
By using the above code the output was looking like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1456 | XXXXXX | 2022-05-27 16:33:44 +0530 (Fri, 27 May 2022) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/new/heelo.txt
test
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the recently committed information in svn repo using svnlog command like this format...

```
Revision: 174
Author: CARDINALHEALTH\enrique.colon
Date: Wednesday, July 11, 2012 9:37:02 AM
Message: CR #58514
----
Modified : /trunk/ob_progs/utility/connect_peek
```

Please help me out with this...

Answer (score -1):

1. **You can't change the format of output for `svn log`**. Period
2. You can try to combine output (by hand!) of a set [`svnlook`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.html#svn.ref.svnlook.c) subcommands in order to get *something similar* (not identical) to needed log-view
3. You can try `svn log --xml` and post-process output

On the rights of delirium: clone svn-repo into git and try to build log output in Git - at least it's somehow configurable